# My route in magento is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7

I have create new module, controller and config file. but the route is not working, showing 404.

**Controller:**

```
<?php
class Magentotutorial_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {        
    public function indexAction() {
        echo 'Hello World';
    }

    public function goodbyeAction() {
    echo 'Goodbye World!';
    }
}
```

**Config file.**

```
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
    </modules>
</config>

<config>    
    ...
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magentotutorial_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**Module:**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your module file would be in this path

`app/etc/module/Magentotutorial_Helloworld.xml`

otherwise I think You have written everything right.

But problem with your `mod_rewrite` please check with this url

> YourBaseURL/index.php/helloworld

And check if its working then enable mod_rewrite in your apache and check again

Comment: Thanks Murtaza. your given route is also not working. as i given http://localhost/magento1.9/index.php/helloworld. showing 404 again. routes are working for another project in magento 2.

Comment: Please provide full detail of your code including the full path of all files

Comment: app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/controllers
app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/etc/config.xml
app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/etc/module

Comment: @KhalilurRehman  your module file should be in `app/etc/module/Magentotutorial_Helloworld.xml`

Comment: yes it is on same location as you said.

Comment: Thanks Murtaza. it was path problem for module file. its working fine now.

Comment: Ok You are always welcome @KhalilurRehman

Comment: Hello Murtaza. i need some more help. i have created new controller, module config file for second model, now how i can create a route for new one. if i create same as i did for first, its not working.

Comment: @KhalilurRehman please provide full code , instead edit this one ask as new question and tag me with @ sign

Answer (score 0):

You have closed the `config` tag and reopened it, this is wrong. Your `config.xml` should look like this:

```
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
    </modules>  
    ...
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magentotutorial_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: @KhalilurRehman how do you access your route ? `http//mysite.com/helloworld` ?

Comment: I am accessing this route.http://localhost/magento1.9/helloworld

Comment: @KhalilurRehman ensure your controller file is located in the `controllers` folder (respect the case). Flush the cache and recompile if you're using the compiler

Comment: controller folder name is controllers. also cleared cache. but i am not compiling my code. how to compile code in magento 1.9 please ? route still showing same issue.

Comment: any other idea ?

Comment: I just created config.xml, module and controller and didnt ran any command to enable or activate any thing and directly checking the url. is it ok or i have to ran any command to activate module or any thing else ?